# Flutter Tabs need to lead to different sections of the same page

Tags: flutter, layout, tabs, navigation

is there anyway to connect the tabs to flutter such that they lead to different sections of one page?
for example if i had a menu, the tabs would be the different categories of food and clicking on a different tab would lead me to a different section in the menu

Answer (score 0):

Use BottomNavigationBar or TabBar

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate please?